# Trigger bootstrap modal without javascript (using if else)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, jinja2, bootstrap-modal

Hello I'm trying to show modal with jinja2 (if - else)

because I can't use javascript.

this is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.98.0">
    <title>lidar - signup </title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/sign-in/">

<link href="../../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }

      .b-example-divider {
        height: 3rem;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        border-width: 1px 0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
      }

      .b-example-vr {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        width: 1.5rem;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .bi {
        vertical-align: -.125em;
        fill: currentColor;
      }

      .nav-scroller {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        height: 2.75rem;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }

      .nav-scroller .nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        margin-top: -1px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      }
    </style>

    
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../../static/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../static/css/modals.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body class="text-center">

  {%if ErrorTitle%}
  <div class="modal modal-sheet position-static d-block bg-secondary py-5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalSheet">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content rounded-4 shadow">
        <div class="modal-header border-bottom-0">
          <h5 class="modal-title">{{ErrorTitle}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label=Close></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body py-0">
          <p>{{ErrorMessage}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer flex-column border-top-0">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary w-100 mx-0 mb-2" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {%endif%}
    
<main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">

  <form method="POST" action="/register">

    <img class="mb-4" src="../../static/image/hashtag.svg" alt="" width="72" height="57">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">register</h1>

    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="id" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="name@example.com" required>
      <label for="floatingInput">id</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="usernick" class="form-control" id="usernick" placeholder="name" required>
        <label for="floatingInput">nickname</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      <label for="floatingPassword">비password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="repassword" placeholder="Password" required>
        <label for="floatingPassword">repassword</label>
    </div>

    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="form_submit" type="submit">signup</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; lidar</p>
  </form>
</main>

</body>
</html>
```

this is error img.
modal popup is slides the existing page sideways.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR1Xu.png

if trigger modal, yes existing page is go away to sideways.

I used bootstrap example.

css also bootstrap example.

How can I fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="margin-top:10%">
```

You can use in-line style to adjust the margin.